# React Native Input Text RTL

Tags: react-native

I have the following situation - when I use rtl text it sticks to the left.

[image]

I've seen react git add a couple of issues related to that, and they were closed.  maybe I don't know how to apply it?

Comment: which react native version you use?

Comment: react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.32.0

Comment: did you try `textAlign: 'right'`

Comment: I can't do that, I'm not targeting specific RTL audience. I need to work both ways.  in android it works great, in my iphone simulator he always start from the left :(

Answer (score 8):

You need to import this :

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'
```

and use this when you want forcing to rtl:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
```

and use `textAlign : "right"` OR `textAlign : "left"` on textInput as when you want use RTL OR LTR.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with text-input in IOS,  I added a condition to styles.

here is my code:

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'
```

and add this to your styles

```
textAlign :  I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
```

Hope it helps Someone,